# Converting from int to double

Tags: assembly, mips32

I'm trying to convert $t5 into a double and so far i've looked everywhere but i still don't get how am i suppose to do it. Can someone please help me

```
li $v0,5
syscall

move $t5,$v0       

l.d $f12,($t5)             #f12 = $t5
cvt.d.w $f0, $f12           #f0 = (int) $t5
```

Comment: You used `$t5` as a pointer there, that's wrong.

Comment: So how's the proper way to do it?